# Redirect based on browser language

Tags: xpages

Here is an issue we are having with our website developed in XPages which is accessible in several regions and languages.  Based on the browser language we are able to determine which header to display at the top of web page.  Our content is then displayed for that language in that region.  Content displayed is from individual documents in a Domino database and there is one for each language so the user can see language friendly data.  Some documents are only for a particular Region/Language and not translated for other regions due to availability of the product.

The issue is when someone clicks on a link (ie via social media let's say) like https://www.cascorp.com/americas/en/reach-forks they go to the americas English version but the header and menu items are displayed in the browser language and content is displayed in the English language.  Server Redirect rules won't work in this case.  It would be nice to be able to redirect them to https://www.cascorp.com/eme/en/reach-forks and have a page that comes up stating that the product is not available for that region.  Is there a way I can dynamically change the address bar to redirect them to a different document by replacing the region part of the address?  This way we can have a document for that region/language stating that the product is not available in their region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.redirectToPage(nameOfXpage)` to redirect based on your language logic.

Answer (score 0):

For a partner of mine, www.the-academy.nl, we decided to abandon Server Redirect rules completely, so we installed Apache as a reverse proxy server. It gives you full control over all links in and out if you want, and we managed to remove all visible references to the web database. Apache can be installed on the same system as Domino (easiest on Linux). It might be a bumpy ride, but it's worth it.